# How to define constant in one file and access in another file in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am handling many variable in my application, I dont want to define the string each and every time. Instead of that I want to access the string from one file and access through all the files in my application.

Eg:

one = 1;

I want to access 1 with the variable name one in my application, because in future it can be changed as one (one = one) that time I cant change in all the place.

In order to avoid such difficulty am going for the constant file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a service and access it in any controller by injecting it.

```
angular.module('app')
.constant('CONSTANTS', {something: 12});
```

your controller

```
angular.module('app').controller('mainCtrl', function (CONSTANTS) {              
    $scope.mainctrlvariable = CONSTANTS.something;
});
```

your another controller

```
angular.module('app').controller('otherCtrl', function (CONSTANTS) {              
        $scope.otherCtrlvariable = CONSTANTS.something;
    });
```

Comment: If am going to user more and more constant mean I can use like this  {something: 12},{one: 1} of {something: 12, one:1}. In which way I have to use

Comment: yes, you can add more and more constants to the hash.... {something: 12, one:1, more: 20, two: 13}.

Comment: okay I will check with it and if its works well I will up you.

Answer (score 1):

Angular provides [constants](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#constant) and [values](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#value) services, that may help you

```
'use strict';
angular
    .module('App', [])
    .constant("config", {
        one:1,
        two:2
    })
    .config(function () { })
    .controller('MainCtrl', function (config) {
        console.log(config.one)
    });
```